# Why isn't the debug module printing the expected output?

Tags: ansible

Expected output is the version of nginx, but it outputs a blank string instead:

```
- hosts: localhost
 tasks:
     - name: check if nginx exists
       stat:
           path: /usr/sbin/nginx
       register: result
     - name: check nginx version
       command: nginx -v
       register: version
     - debug: msg="{{version.stdout}}"
```

I am getting the below output instead:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Comment: Please take note that [some software packages like Java, Python, Nginx are reporting his version to `stderr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483443/). You may also take advantage from [Whats the best way in Ansible to check if a command is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70812235/6771046).

Answer (score 3):

It's because `nginx -v` sends its output to stderr, as one can see with

```bash
$ nginx -v >/dev/null
nginx version: nginx/1.23.3
$ nginx -v 2>/dev/null
$
```

so your output is actually in `version.stderr`, as you would have seen for yourself had you increased the ansible verbosity or used

```yaml
- debug: var=version
```